# Angular MomentDateTimeAdapter not building after angular 8 update

Tags: angular

after updating my angular project I faced some probles due to the breaking changes. Now I have got an Problem with my MomentDateTimeAdapter. I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime-moment) one.(/ng-pick-datetime-moment).

My application is running perfectly in dev mode but as soon as i try to build productive (`ng build --prod`) Im getting this error:

> ERROR in
>   ..\ng-pick-datetime-moment\moment-adapter\moment-date-time-adapter.class.ts(46,2):
>   Error during template compile of 'MomentDateTimeAdapter'   Function
>   calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called
>   in 'Injectable'
>       'Injectable' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.

I took every step described in the angular-update tutorial and updated all my dependencies. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know why but I found [this github entry](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/issues/23).

By just adding: `"paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] },` into my `tsconfig.app.json` the build is working again.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `ng-pick-datetime-moment`-package is embedded with angular 7.

The MomentDateTimeAdapter is also included in the `ng-pick-datetime`-package. (v 7.0.0)
No need to import from `ng-pick-datetime-moment` package, but `from ng-pick-datetime package`.

```
import { MomentDateTimeAdapter, OWL_MOMENT_DATE_TIME_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from 'ng-pick-datetime/date-time/adapter/moment-adapter/moment-date-time-adapter.class';
```

Comment: For future reference: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/issues/520#issuecomment-455819408

Comment: But as told in the link provided by @edoDev, this method does not work in Angular 8 and above. Please refer given link for Angular 9 and above - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mat-datetimepicker/core) the @mat-datetimepicker/core description. So different Angular versions should use different versions of the package.

> You can find the Angular 8 version on the 3.x branch.
> You can find the Angular 9 version on the 4.x branch.
> You can find the Angular 10 version on the 5.x branch.

I changed versions of these dependencies in package.json and it helped

Before(Angular 8):
`"@mat-datetimepicker/core": "3.0.0-beta.0",
"@mat-datetimepicker/moment": "3.0.0-beta.0",`

After(Angular 9):
`"@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^4.0.0",
"@mat-datetimepicker/moment": "^4.0.0",`